# MySQL alternative to Read/Modify/Write a field

Tags: php, mysql

In several PHP codes I have to just increment a field value from a MySQL DB.
Tipically, I use this snippet:

```
$sql = "SELECT IDpage, numPages FROM Pages WHERE IDpage=".$page;
$result = mysqli_query( $conn,$sql)
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$num = $row['numPages'] + 1;

$sql = "UPDATE Pages SET numPages=".$num." WHERE IDpage=".$page;;
$result = mysqli_query( $conn,$sql)
```

Is there any more elegant and concise method?

Comment: Why do the increment in PHP at all? Once you've got the page id you could just do something like `UPDATE Pages SET numPages = numPages + 1 WHERE IDPage = ?`

Comment: I would recommend looking into prepared statement especially when updating https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to fetch the data first, just do the update.

```php
$sql = "UPDATE Pages SET numPages = numPages + 1 WHERE IDpage = ".$page;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Also, your snippet is missing a few semicolons.

Comment: You are right; I did not know that MySQL can perform directly the increment. The snipped is missing a couple of semicolons just because I copied them too fast.